# Why sometime mysql will update twice

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my very basic code. I need help cause sometime my statement below will update twice.

```
$queryCS="Select * FROM coin_market_sell";
$resultCS=mysql_query($queryCS);
while($rowCS=mysql_fetch_array($resultCS)){
  $cms_id=$rowCS['cms_id'];
  $cms_by=$rowCS['cms_by'];
  $cms_coin_amount_balance=$rowCS['cms_coin_amount_balance'];
  $cms_coin_id=$rowCS['cms_coin_id'];
  $wallet_amountnew=0;

  $queryCOIN2="Select * FROM wallet WHERE user_id=$cms_by and currency_id=$cms_coin_id";
  $resultCOIN2=mysql_query($queryCOIN2);
  while($rowCOIN2=mysql_fetch_array($resultCOIN2)){
    $wallet_id=$rowCOIN2['wallet_id'];
    $wallet_amount=$rowCOIN2['wallet_amount'];
    $wallet_amountnew=$wallet_amount+$cms_coin_amount_balance;
  }

  mysql_query("UPDATE wallet SET wallet_amount='$wallet_amountnew' WHERE wallet_id='$wallet_id'");
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM `coin_market_sell` WHERE `coin_market_sell`.`cms_id` = $cms_id");
}
```

Comment: Add the rest of the code... make sure $query1 is not called twice

Comment: **Stop** using the outdated `mysql_* API`. Move to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: please help me on this. I am calling coin_market_sell table unsold balance and add back to user wallet database but problem is sometime will update twice. example now user A wallet has 100 then unsold in table have 50 suppose add up will be 150 as new amount but it show 200 in database mean is 100+50+50

Answer (score 0):

Î am not hundred percent sur what you are trying to, but i think the  `UPDATE`statment must be inside of the inner loop:

```
 $queryCOIN2="Select * FROM wallet WHERE user_id=$cms_by and currency_id=$cms_coin_id";
  $resultCOIN2=mysql_query($queryCOIN2);
  while($rowCOIN2=mysql_fetch_array($resultCOIN2)){
    $wallet_id=$rowCOIN2['wallet_id'];
    $wallet_amount=$rowCOIN2['wallet_amount'];
    $wallet_amountnew=$wallet_amount+$cms_coin_amount_balance;
    mysql_query("UPDATE wallet SET wallet_amount='$wallet_amountnew' WHERE wallet_id='$wallet_id'");

  }
```

BTW: **Stop** using the outdated `mysql_*` API. Move to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: please help me on this. I am calling coin_market_sell table unsold balance and add back to user wallet database but problem is sometime will update twice. example now user A wallet has 100 then unsold in table have 50 suppose add up will be 150 as new amount but it show 200 in database mean is 100+50+50